# Change warning messages in php

Tags: php

change their warning messages in php

> Warning: include (tools / test_db / viewposta.php) [function.include]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D: \ program files
>   \ Server xampp \ xampp \ htdocs \ projc \ writecode \ tools \ terminal
>   \ run.php on line 45
>
> Warning: include () [function.include]: Failed opening 'tools /
>   test_db / viewposta.php' for inclusion (include_path = '.; D: \
>   program files \ Server xampp \ xampp \ php \ PEAR') in D: \ program
>   files \ Server xampp \ xampp \ htdocs \ projc \ writecode \ tools \
>   terminal \ run.php on line 45

be

> Error at \projc\writecode\tools\terminal\run.php on line 45.

Comment: Production side: Turn error reporting off. Development side: Be glad, that they're much more detailed like you want them to be.

Comment: Look into php [exceptions](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp)

Comment: @Daniel: I believe that only applies to checks that you make before hand. If the error happens directly on a php function, such as include, you can't throw anything because it's PHP that is throwing an error.

Comment: @David - You are correct at that, however one might make a routine that checks beforehand if the `file_exists` and throw a controller error message with an exception.

Comment: Ah nice catch, it was `not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are within a class, I recommend looking at `set_error_handler` from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

```
set_error_handler(
    function($level,$msg,$file,$line) {
        echo "Error at ".$file." on line ".$line;
        exit;
    }
);
```

Comment: This works well,
but it does not run on My program.

Comment: Even though this question is closed. What does your program look like?

Comment: wait.
This really works well
in the case
I made the switch case
I incorrectly put in the switch
switch should be outside
include 'config / error.php';
switch($se)
{
case :
break;
}